# Reverse engineer IIS site to powershell commands

Tags: powershell, iis

I know that I can create/configure IIS sites using Powershell. What I want to do is take an existing IIS website, in this case a legacy ASP site and generate the Powershell commands to recreate the site. I'm going to then use the Powershell script in a Dockerfile so I can containerize this thing and get it into Azure and out of my datacenter. Is there a tool or library out there that can do this?

Comment: While that's a valid use case, I don't recall anything inside IIS provides exact the things you wanted. But Microsoft has another approach, https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/announcement-adding-webdeploy-support-to-container-image/ba-p/1579144

Comment: As far as I know, there is no specific tool or library that can directly convert an existing IIS website configuration to PowerShell commands. But you can do this by manually inspecting the existing IIS configuration and writing a corresponding PowerShell script.